# Why is my weight painting screen so dim?

Tags: weight-painting

I'm trying to weight pain on one of my meshes but for some reason the colors are very dim and its hard to see the weights. I have another window open painting another mesh and the colors are bright and clear like they're supposed to be. Whats wrong here?

Here's what I'm looking at. The one on the left is obviously the one thats too dim, the one on the right is how its supposed to be looking.
[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to due to client demands but could you imagine any reasons this might cause it without it?

Comment: there was a similar question several weeks ago but I don't remember, maybe just keep a part of the mesh if you don't want to share the whole thing